# Why do the Thunderbolt specifications indicate a max length for the cable?

Tags: cable, thunderbolt, specifications

The [Thunderbolt specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) indicate a max length for the cable. Why?

[image]

Comment: Resistance, capacity, reflections, propagation speed thru copper, crosstalking. There are many physical effects which hinder us to just send a few PBit/s thru a 1km cable. To say it in very basic terms; the longer the cable, the noisier the signal.

Comment: @mashuptwice Thanks. Why having that in the specs instead of leaving it up to the manufacturer to see what the possible length is while respecting the rest of the specs?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - The more strict a standard is the better the standard ultimately is, Case in point, USB and HDMI standard's community, are not strict with it's labeling policy which creates confusion when purchasing an actual cable.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Did you ever buy a device that didn't work with some other device, albeit they should be compatible by specification? Imagine that happening with every device you buy. It would be a gamble instead of a just-worx© situation

Comment: @mashuptwice if they didn't work with some other device, I'd guess one of them doesn't follow the specification.

Comment: You don't leave it to the cable manufacturers because all they want to do is make cables. When length, individual strand length matching, wiring as twisted pairs, wire thickness and other features actually matter then you do not leave it up to manufacturers to guess what might work, you tell them what **will** work. If they go out of specification and it doesn't work then you know who to blame.

Comment: That's not the Thunderbolt spec, that's a Wikipedia page. The Thunderbolt spec is not an open standard. You apparently have to sign a Thunderbolt developer contract (including NDAs, presumably) with Intel to get the spec. If the actual spec does indeed specify a maximum length, it's probably because that's easier than enforcing a complicated signal integrity testing & certification regime.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there a maximum length of copper based Thunderbolt 3 cables.

The reason the length of a copper cable is important is due to the fact Thunderbolt 3 transfer speeds is 40 Gbit/s, so any digital standard capable of similar speeds, will have length limits. These length limits will either be specifically specified or simply be theoretical.

Copper based HDMI and DisplayPort cables, both encounter sever signal degradation, at lengths beyond their specified compatible lengths.

**Optical cables for these standards do not have the same limitations, due to the physics, that surround optical cables.**

Comment: Thanks, doesn't 40 Gbit/s already placed a limit of the cable max length without the latter having to be specified?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - The performance of Thunderbolt standard has increased through it's multiple revisions.  As the performance increased, the length of a cable that worked at the specification's specified performance, would also decrease.  Of course the entire premises of this question, is under the assumption, that Wikipedia has the maximum length of the cable correct,  Although that wouldn't change the reason there is a maximum length, just the value, and the reason optical cables would be allowed to be longer.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The point of the limit is to allow _reliable_ communication by staying well within the physical limits.

Comment: Degradation does not *have* to happen beyond the specified length.

Comment: @harrymc - What exactly are you trying to say, I feel the statement is accurate, signal degradation will happen once the maximum length is exceeded.  It’s not the only instance where signal degradation can happen, but I never made that claim, I just didn’t go into the dozens of other reasons it might happen.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't contest your answer. What I say is that if the maximum is N meters, the degradation may perhaps not be felt at N+1. I don't believe in sharp cutoffs.